# Is there a Builder like interface in java.* in JDK 1.5 or before?

Tags: java, android, jvm

I wonder whether there is a Builder like interface in `java.*`
as described by Joshua Block [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2). I only find the following 
interface:

```
public interface Builder<T> {
   public T build();
}
```

in two places:

```
package javafx.util;
package com.sun.istack.internal;
```

Is there something similar in `java.*` preferably JDK 1.5?
So that I could use it both on the Android and the Java platform.
I notice I could also use:

```
public interface Supplier<T> {
  T get();
}
```

But the above is only in JDK 1.8.

Comment: What do you expect a Builder to do exactly? Finding a class/interface based on such a generic name only doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Why do you need an interface to be built-in? Why not create one yourself?

Comment: What possible disadvantages can creating your own interface have, besides the obvious?

Comment: If you search far and wide you might find a Java5+ interface with only one arbitrarily named no-arg method that returns a generic type, but it would likely be for a specific purpose that not "builder", so what's the point? Create your own!

Comment: Why is different class loaders an issue? Any implementing class would be from different class loaders, so you still have class loader issues to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for class/interface with that exact name then there is no such class/interface in any JDK from 5 to 8.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

EDIT: So if you want Builder interface described in Effective Java then for sure there is no such interface. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: Well it could have a slightly different name, just as Supplier has. But it needs to be part of JDK 1.5. I wouldn't mind if its not exactly named Builder, as long as the signature fits.

Answer (score 0):

Is Java EE alright? Provider seems to satisfy your (strange:)) requirements.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html

Comment: Would match, what concerns the signature, but somehow I don't find it in the JDK.

Comment: Yup, it belongs to the java ee api http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0

Answer (score 0):

I did a structural search with IntelliJ 1.4.3,
using the following pattern:

```
public interface $Class$<T> {
    public T $method$();
}
```

Which gives me:

```
public interface PrivilegedAction<T> {
    T run();
}
```

I checked its part of JDK 1.5. See also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html).
Not sure whether I should go with this interface.

Bye